# Can I footcite something from a footnote with biblatex?

Tags: citing, footnotes, nesting

I have a relatively long footnote with some explanatory text that refers to some citations. My current approach is to use `\footnotemark` where I want to cite something and then `\fotnotetext{\cite[xx]{yyy}}` after the footnote to insert the citation. However this generates weird newlines withing the citation footnotes. Here is what I have:

```
This is the main body.\footnote{%
Here we have some text that provides additional background and 
detail,\footnotemark referencing citations when needed.}%
\footnotetext{\cite[xxx]{yyy}}
```

Since this doesn't really work, is there a cleaner/'correct' way to cite from within a footnote?

Comment: First question: Why do you "nest" `\footnote`s? Can't you just put the citation in place of your `\footnotemark`?

Comment: The footnote becomes very unreadable at parts because it is clustered full with citations, e.g. "he did this,(cite) this,(cite), and this,(cite) leading to whatever."

Comment: What about doing something like this `\footnote{Lorem ipsum\textsuperscript{*} \newline * citation}`? You could also look at the `bigfoot`or the `manyfoot` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please see also: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @Georg. Thanks, that actually doesn't look too bad.

Comment: @Georg Your comment sounds suitable for an answer, would you please convert it?

Comment: Why not just `\cite`?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be `\footnote{Lorem ipsum\textsuperscript{*} \newline * citation}` which gives the following output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{%
Here we have some text that provides additional background and detail,\textsuperscript{*} referencing citations when needed.%
\newline * your citation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The packages `bigfoot` and `manyfoot` would give you more advanced and automated options.